# After answering a question a deeper discussion started in the chat

Tags: discussion, chat

I recently answered on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41415263/problems-with-updating-c-sharp-variables-in-javascript) that in my opinion had some bigger issues, where the user who asked the question had problems understanding the code they wrote themselves.

I invited the user into the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132013/discussion-between-icepickle-and-jessica) and it became rather a learning experience for both me and the user in question.

From my perspective, I miscalculated the user's knowledge of the language, and possibly made my first answer too hard, after which I took the approach to rather tutor the user. From the user's perspective, the answer was first frustrating as she felt that she understood less and less what the solution would entail, but in the end, I could point the user to learn more about the language and to do a bit more research before starting to code.

Now I feel that the answer to the question might be incomplete, since I rather offered the user to help more in teaching them how to step back and analyse the problem from a distance.

Though the invitation to the chat is inside the comments, I am unsure if I should add the link chat as part of the answer, or if both the question and the answer need some extra editing to make it clear that the answer in the end is part of a bigger solution.

Should I add the link to the chat inside the answer, and what is communities view on solving a question with an extended chat between the OP and the answerer?

Comment: There is no golden formula for this.  Other than to be pretty wary of these one-on-one tutor sessions, they tend to leave you with two fang marks on your neck.  Only decent advice is to write your answer for the next thousand professional programmers that are going to read it some day.  She's just one.

Comment: @HansPassant True, I also thought about the Help vampire, however, from my side, it was in this case an interesting scenario to rather tutor instead of quick helping, in the end I also tended to not do that much coding anymore, but rather point her to better resources or specifics she might find helpful, so she could improve the code herself, which I hope, in the end worked

Comment: The chat will get pruned eventually by the way, so linking to it does not really help. Besides that, the answer is perfectly fine. An answer does not become too hard because the person asking the question lacks skill, there will be dozens of others who did inform themselves well enough that will benefit from the answer as-is.